# Java failed to read in data from evaluated excel formula using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to use excel to calculate the cdf of normal distribution by input x into excel and read the output of cdf(x) from excel. The excel can be created and calculated correctly. However java cannot read the result from excel correctly.

Here are the relevant code:

```
private double cdfxls1(double x) throws IOException{
    double cdf=0;

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("1");
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    HSSFCell input = row.createCell(0);
    input.setCellValue(x);
    HSSFCell output = row.createCell(1);
    output.setCellFormula("NORMDIST(A1,0,1,1)");

    wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);


    /* Using the FormulaEvaluator, still doesn't work
    Cell tempoutput=row.getCell(1);
    tempoutput.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);     
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    evaluator.evaluateInCell(tempoutput);
    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(tempoutput);
    System.out.println("tempoutput "+tempoutput.getNumericCellValue());
    System.out.println("output "+output.getNumericCellValue());
    */

    //Using evaluateall, doesn't work either
    //  HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);


    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("cdf_cal.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    cdf=output.getNumericCellValue();       

    return cdf;
}
```

I tried three methods for recalculating the formula. However, none of them worked. I also tried close and reopen the excel. It doesn't work as well. I also tried to use '.csv' as output file instead of '.xls'. It doesn't work either and the cell in csv file contains the formula. When I opened the spreadsheet created, the formula and value are all correct. However, the java can only output 0, the initial value, to me.

**Update:**

The error message shows:
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: NORMDIST
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.NotImplementedFunction.evaluate(NotImplementedFunction.java:42)

These means the normdist function has not been supported and I need to implement it myself. See the list of function supported here:
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html

Is there any way that I just let excel to calculate it and I read the result from excel sheet?

Comment: What's the result when using the `FormulaEvaluator` as commented in your code?

Comment: I changed the code a little bit. The FormulaEvaluator doesn't work. The outputted excel file have the correct answer. However, the output in java is 0 as well

Comment: Is implementing the NORMDIST function an option? (+ ideally contributing it back to Apache POI!) Excel functions aren't that difficult to write, for someone who knows what a given function does